# Joomla Migration Control Panel inaccessible

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, joomla

In the process of migrating a Joomla website to AWS Ubuntu instance, I could restore a backup with success and I am able to run the website without problem.

But I cant use Control Panel, no matter what I do.

When I sign in, Joomla immediately sends an

`'Cannot open file for writing log'`.

When I click on 'Return to Control Panel', it logs me out immediately.

I have checked configuration.php again and again and it is ok.

When I chmod the logs folder, it gets even more strange.
after `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/joomla/logs` I cant even sign in anymore and the Login screen answers :

```
Unable to connect to LDAP server
```

Changing chmod back to 755 brings me back to the message with the writing log problem.

So I think it is about granting rights, but dont know how to fix this.

Comment: Try doing chmod  775

Comment: no way, didnt work.
I did a complete re-install and now it works. weird.